# Python app using TKInter on startup

Tags: python, tkinter, autostart

I've searched the web and couldn't find the working example of launching python script when the graphic interface has been loaded.I've installed upstart, but it seems that there is no way to run the script at the point when TKInter is able to open a window and draw graphics in it.

Can someone please point me to the right direction or maybe some helpful article?

Comment: "on startup": on startup of what? Of the system as a whole?

Comment: On my Fluxbox window manager, it is added to the ~/.fluxbox/startup script.  You may also be able to add it to ~/.xinitrc depending again on what the window manger reads at startup.  Note that this is not a Tkinter question and should also be asked on the forum for whatever window manager you are using.